# Python: calling def from a different def

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python and I've been stuck on something that seems very trivial, so hoping someone can help.

What I'm trying to do is call a method inside a method in Python. I want to call this method several times, in various different methods, so I don't want to have to keep on copying and pasting the code if I'm going to be using it ~10 times - just to keep calling that "def".

I have tried things such as:

```
return anotherMethod()
```

Any ideas how to do this?!

Thanks!

Edit:
Sorry about the vagueness of the question. I'm trying to get my head around the terminology.

```
def scaleC():

   pianoIcon = Icon("PianoScaleC.png")
   d1 = Display("iPiano", pianoIcon.getWidth(), pianoIcon.getHeight())
   d1.add(pianoIcon)
   return piano()

def scaleCS():

    pianoIcon = Icon("PianoScaleCS.png")
    d1 = Display("iPiano", pianoIcon.getWidth(), pianoIcon.getHeight())
    d1.add(pianoIcon)
    return piano()

def piano:
#play the piano keys, etc
```

Comment: I think we need some more context to understand where you're going wrong, can you edit your post to include more of your example code?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `self.anotherMethod()`?

Comment: You can't "call" a function inside a function. The inner function lives in a different namespace than your environment and thus it cannot be accessed *directly* (it can be accessed indirectly by returning a pointer to the inner function in the return statement of the wrapping function). Read about [decorators](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) to get more context in regards.

Comment: @alfasin, that's true if it's "inside" a function meaning defined within it. If it's "call a function inside a function" meaning "call a function _from_ a function", that's a different matter.

Comment: @alfasin yeah, it's still not clear whether this is about functions defined within other functions, so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: ...that that's a question is probably a pretty good indicator that this question is too vaguely asked to be actionable at this time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if by the word "inside" the OP means "from" then this question is indeed poorly worded. Voting to close it as "unclear"

Comment: @figub I'm not sure how much clearer your edit is, example code that demonstrates the problem would be best.

Comment: ...also, calling a thing a "def" doesn't clarify whether it's a function or a method. Many of the answers given here assume that the OP wants methods, whereas from the amended question it appears that it's functions that are actually wanted -- just one more ambiguity that showing code helps to solve. :)

Comment: @figub, ...that said, I don't know that your code shows a _problem_ -- because the code you gave should (other than `def piano:`, by virtue of not being `def piano():`) generally work. This is part of why examples should be complete and correct enough that someone else can copy-and-paste them and get your same error; if you depend on libraries or functions that aren't shown rather than being self-contained, nobody else can be guaranteed to reproduce your problem. See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines when writing future questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy apologies! I'm very new to this stuff and trying to get to grips with it. I will take on board what you've mentioned for future questions. Thanks for the guidelines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well it is quite simple. You just literally call that function inside your other function. Here is an example:

```
def Examples():
    print 'Function successfully called!'

def Example()
    print 'Calling function...'
    Examples()   #This will call the function above it

Example()
```

Your result should be:

```
Calling function...
Function successfully called!
```

No errors should pop up and this should work. Just add a variable:

```
loop = 0
```

and put the functions in a while loop:

```
while loop <> 10:
    loop += 1
    def Examples():
        print 'Function successfully called!'

    def Example()
        print 'Calling function...'
        Examples()   #This will call the function above it

    Example()
```

This will should solve your problem. I hope this helps you! Your final code with this implied should be:

```
loops = 0
while loops <> 10:
    loops += 1
    def scaleC():
       pianoIcon = Icon("PianoScaleC.png")
       d1 = Display("iPiano", pianoIcon.getWidth(), pianoIcon.getHeight())
       d1.add(pianoIcon)
       piano()

    def scaleCS():

        pianoIcon = Icon("PianoScaleCS.png")
        d1 = Display("iPiano", pianoIcon.getWidth(), pianoIcon.getHeight())
        d1.add(pianoIcon)
        piano()

   def piano:
       #play the piano keys, etc
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I don't want to sound too harsh, but... Why are you defining functions in a `while`-loop? Your version of the OP's code has a syntax error (`def piano:`). You're using the deprecated inequality symbol (use `!=`, not `<>`). I'd suggest you use clearer names than `Examples` and `Example` for your functions (and stick to PEP8 and make the function names lowercase).

Comment: It doesn't really matter...

Comment: It actually does matter quite a bit, if you're going to be a "PythonMaster" you should use best practices... people in the future should find these tidbits of information and feel confident they are getting good information, not a slew of errors or bad practices.

Comment: Now we judge people by their names?!

Comment: People like something called nicknames you know!!

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing something like this?:

```
def my_global_function():
    def my_local_function():
        print('hello world')

    my_local_function()
```

And then outside of that definition you want to call that function again?
But it has been destroyed because you exited the scope.

You can make it a global then:

```
my_local_function_global_scope = None

def my_global_function():
    def my_local_function():
        print('hello world')

    # Declare variable space as global and assign to it
    global my_local_function_global_scope
    my_local_function_global_scope = my_local_function

    my_local_function()

my_local_function_global_scope()
```

Comment: Why did you answer twice?

Comment: @PythonMaster the first one had downvotes which were not representative of the new suggestion's example

Answer (score -1):

SO you want to call the same function/method ten times? Do it in a loop eh?

```
for i in range(10):
    print('Iteration Number %s' % i)
    anotherMethod()
```

if you want to return the results of the function ten times in a list, you can use *list comprehension*

```
return [anotherMethod() for _ in range(10)]
```

*Note: the `_` variable is a convention used when you are required to have an assignment but you do not want to store that variable, naming it `_` will effectively delete it as I understand.*

my last idea is that you wan to reference the callable once and call it ten times. You can do that too (And its one of my favorite things about python)

```
my_method = anotherMethod

my_method()
my_method()
...
my_method()
my_method()
```

Comment: I don't believe this to be at all what is being asked.  Their original intent is just to assume that it may be called some arbitrary number of times.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking on how to define methods in Python that can be called from everywhere you can write the method you want on a library.py file like this:

```
def fun(a , b):
    return a + b
```

and then call it from another file (ie. program.py) like this:

```
from library import fun

def main():
    # your code
    print fun(1, 2)
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = fun(a, b)
    print c

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

this will output:

```
3
9
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question right, you just need to use it like this.

```
class YourClass(object):
    def method(self):
        pass # here goes your method
    def method_where_i_want_to_use_other_method(self):
        self.method()
    #other things you need in this method
```

Comment: Err. You mean `def method_where_i_want_to_use_other_method(self):`, surely?

Comment: Yes, surely I mean def before this second method. I can add pass in his program those functions are not empty.